# Makefile path issues

Tags: c, makefile

I've .c files in different subfolders within main src directory, I've the problem with running Makefile, I'm new to Makefile, need hands on the Makefile to work and to create a static library.

**src/math/addition/add.c** (+add.h)

```
int add(int a, int b) {return a + b;}
```

**src/math/subtraction/sub.c** (+sub.h)

```
 int sub(int a, int b) {return a - b;}
```

**src/math/math.c**

```
 #include "addition/add.h"
 #include "subtraction/sub.h"
```

**Makefile** (at the root of the project)

```
SRC=src/math/Math.c src/math/Math.h src/math/addition/add.c src/math/addition/add.h src/math/subtraction/sub.c src/math/subtraction/sub.h
INCLUDE_PATH=src/

Math: bin
    ar rcs libMath.a Math.o

bin:
    mkdir bin/
    for dir in $(SRC); do \ 
        cd $$dir; \
        gcc -c *.c -I../; \ 
        mv *.o ../../../bin; \ 
        cd -; \
    done
```

If you believe there's a better way or any lateral thinking, I'm not fixated on anything.

Comment: I guess you shouldn't use `cd`.

Comment: Thanks @iBug, I'm new to this, I guess if add or remove lines etc. I'd introduce more bugs, if you can please create the structure and files in your computer and run, i'd highly appreciate.

Comment: Note: you can't have backslash continuation followed by comments in a Makefile.

Comment: @Jens, thanks, removing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Makefile is good at two things: building dependency graphs and executing steps between each node in the dependency graphs.

If you have access to GNUMake (most of us do; it's pretty much the only one anyone uses), you can use `VPATH` to tidy up a bit. `VPATH` is used to tell make where it can find source files. Be careful with it, if you have multiple files with the same name under different directories.

I suggest you use something akin to the following

```
VPATH := src src/math src/math/addition src/math/subtraction
CFLAGS += -Isrc -Isrc/math -Isrc/mathaddition -Isrc/math/subtraction
all: libMath

libMath: bin/Math.o bin/add.o bin/sub.o
    ar rcs libMath bin/Math.o bin/add.o bin/sub.o

bin/%.o: %.c %.h
```

Make contains a default .c -> .o rule which you can use; the `%.o: %.c %.h`does this, but also declares that all `.o` files, *by default*, depend on a `.c` and a `.h` file with the same prefix (the `%` part) as the object file.

I suspect your `Math.o` target will also depend on the `addition.h` and `subtraction.h` files; you can declare `Math.o` as dependent on those files using the rule `Math.o: Math.c Math.h addition.h subtraction.h`.

Remember to substitute the space before ar, with a tab.

You may want to change how you organize your source files and/or header files.

Usually `ar` produces archive files that end in `.a`. You may want to change that as well.

If you use make right, you can use parallel builds (`make -J`) to really speed up compilation time; if you use it wrong, everything is going to get slower and we'll have yet another person who starts to hate make because they don't understand it.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting `Makefile:6: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

Comment: Did you replace the spaces before the command `ar` with a tab?

Comment: sorry, my IDE changed tab to spaces. I want to put all .o files in the bin directory, any articulate suggestions?

Comment: also, what's the industry convention to reduce the .o clutter, I'll have several .c files and therefore .o files and all I need is one file libMath.a in the bin directory

Comment: I never found a solution I was really happy with, but slapping `bin/` in front of all your `.o` files and `%.o` should do the trick. You can also replace the rule to build libMath with `ar rcs $@ $<` (or `ar rcs $@ $^` -- I always get it wrong), to make make `ar` build $@ (libMath in this case) from `@^`/`@<`, so you don't have to change it more than one place.

Comment: I don't know if there's a need to remove ".o clutter". Try declareing a target `clean:` that doesn't depend on anything and let it execute the `$(RM) libMath *.o` command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163701/discussion-between-clearer-and-developer).

Comment: `but slapping bin/ in front of all your .o files and %.o`, having some issues, can you please test and update the answer. I updated `ar rcs bin/libMath Math.o add.o sub.o`

Comment: quick question. is it necessary to have `int main() { return 0; }` in the math.c, otherwise compiler complains, `file: bin/libMath(Math.o)` has no symbols

Comment: You should only implement `main`, if you're writing a full program. `ar` is for creating archives. If `Math.c` doesn't contain anything but a main function, I'd drop it.

Comment: there'd be a struct in the Math.c but no main function, so can i skip the main function and ignore compiler complain?

Comment: I'll tag you tomorrow with another question that deals with unit tests, same example but with unit tests on the .a file using cmocka or please advise.

Comment: `struct`s should be defined in header files, to make them available without dragging code along with it.

Comment: Thanks for the looking after :) so basically all data goes into .h along with forward declarations of the method and the code goes into .c

Comment: hi, basically taking this example further and adding unit tests with cmocka. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48412862/unit-test-run-configuration please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Makefile:

```
#
# Boilerplate.
#
all:

define add_target
    $(info add_target($1))
    $(eval $(eval_args))
    $(eval $(call eval_args,$1,\
        OBJDIR := $(firstword $($1.OBJDIR) ./objs/$1),\
    ))
    $(eval $(call eval_args,$1,\
        TYPE := $(firstword $($1.TYPE) binary),\
    ))
    $(eval $(call eval_args,$1,\
        objs := $(obj_from_source),
    ))
    $(eval $1 := $($1.TARGET))

    TARGETS += $($1)
    PHONY_TARGETS += $1
    CLEAN_TARGETS += clean_$1

    .PHONY: clean_$1
    clean_$1:; rm -rf $($1.OBJDIR) $($1)

    .PHONY: $1
    $1: $($1)

    $($1): target:=$1
    $($1): $($1.objs); $$(if $$(wildcard $$(@D)),,mkdir -p $$(@D) && )$$(add_target.link)
    $($1.objs):; $$(if $$(wildcard $$(@D)),,mkdir -p $$(@D) && )$$(add_target.compile)
    $(foreach $1.SOURCES,$($1.SOURCES),$(eval $(obj_from_source): $($1.SOURCES)))

    $(info end)
endef

void :=
space := $(void) $(void)
obj_from_source = $(addprefix $($1.OBJDIR)/,$(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(notdir $($1.SOURCES)))))
eval_args = $(foreach i,2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9,$(call eval_arg,$1,$(strip $($i))))
eval_arg = $(if $2,$(info $(space)$(space)$1.$2)$(eval $1.$2))

# Link command line
add_target.link_binary = $(CC) $($(target).LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^
add_target.link_lib = $(AR) rcs $@ $^
add_target.link = $(add_target.link_$($(target).TYPE))

# Compile command line
add_target.compile = $(CC) -c -o $@ $($(target).CFLAGS) $<


# -- Directories --
SRC_ROOT := ./src
BIN := ./bin


# Add 'math' target to the project
$(eval $(call add_target,math,\
    TYPE := lib,\
    TARGET := $(BIN)/math.a,\
    SOURCES +=  ${SRC_ROOT}/math/addition/add.c\
                ${SRC_ROOT}/math/subtraction/sub.c\
                ${SRC_ROOT}/math/math.c,\
    CFLAGS := -Wall -I./$(SRC_ROOT)/math,\
))


all: ${PHONY_TARGETS}
.PHONY: all

clean: | $(CLEAN_TARGETS)
.PHONY: clean
```

Directory structure:

```
$ find
.
./Makefile
./src
./src/math
./src/math/addition
./src/math/addition/add.c
./src/math/addition/add.h
./src/math/math.c
./src/math/subtraction
./src/math/subtraction/sub.c
./src/math/subtraction/sub.h
```

File contents:

```
$ find src/ -type f -exec sh -c "echo Contents of {} file:; cat {}; echo" \;
Contents of src/math/addition/add.c file:
int add(int a, int b) {return a + b;}

Contents of src/math/addition/add.h file:
int add(int a, int b);

Contents of src/math/math.c file:
#include "addition/add.h"
#include "subtraction/sub.h"

Contents of src/math/subtraction/sub.c file:
int add(int a, int b) {return a - b;}

Contents of src/math/subtraction/sub.h file:
int add(int a, int b);
```

Running Makefile:

```
$ make
add_target(math)
  math.TYPE := lib
  math.TARGET := ./bin/math.a
  math.SOURCES += ./src/math/addition/add.c ./src/math/subtraction/sub.c ./src/math/math.c
  math.CFLAGS := -Wall -I././src/math
  math.OBJDIR := ./objs/math
  math.TYPE := lib
  math.objs := ./objs/math/add.o ./objs/math/sub.o ./objs/math/math.o
end
mkdir -p objs/math && cc -c -o objs/math/add.o -Wall -I././src/math src/math/addition/add.c
cc -c -o objs/math/sub.o -Wall -I././src/math src/math/subtraction/sub.c
cc -c -o objs/math/math.o -Wall -I././src/math src/math/math.c
mkdir -p bin && ar rcs bin/math.a objs/math/add.o objs/math/sub.o objs/math/math.o
```

This general purpose makefile is missing some important features, like tracking .h file dependencies, linking with static/dynamic libraries, etc. Extend it with the features you need yourself.